# Jobs RSS feed: limit result items

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

I'm using the RSS feed URL `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?q=wordpress` but it's super slow as it seems to be downloading 1000 results. Is there a way to paginate or limit the returned results?

Comment: [no-repro] 40KB loaded in 665ms.

Comment: @SamuelLiew how do you load it? If I pate it in the browser I get abut 100kb, which is not the same if I load it through an RSS reader or PHP. Then it loads 1000 items. In the browser only 10.

Comment: Please provide more information in your question itself.

Comment: @SamuelLiew as the question states, I'm wondering if I can limit the results because it's slow on my end. I'm including the RSS feed URL I'm using. What more info can I provide? If someone comments they can't reproduce this (as in, the slowness), my question still seems valid? Please consider reopening.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow's Q&A feeds as well as Jobs RSS feeds do not support a pagesize parameter.